# Strange log message in IntelliJ IDEA console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logback, owl-api

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and the following log message appears in the output console:

```
#logback.classic pattern: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

This happens when I call [`OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager()`](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/apibinding/OWLManager.html#createOWLOntologyManager--). I also tried to run a program containing just this method call and the message is logged anyway.

I'm not importing anything related to [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) in my pom.xml, so I can't figure out what this can be related to.

Comment: If you are unsure where your dependencies come from you can run ```mvn dependency:tree``` to inspect which library imports what. I'm sure that a library you import in you pom imports logback.

Comment: OWLAPI does not use logback either so there must be another dependency in your pom causing the message to appear. Can you add your pom to the question?